# unable to import azureml in vscode

Tags: python, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-devops, azureml-python-sdk

I've installed python 3.8, from vscode terminal I created an env and seem to have successfully installed azureml as below:

```
C:\Python38\python.exe -m venv tempml
tempml\scripts\activate
pip install azureml-core
```

I then go into python and type

```
import azureml
```

but I get the following error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azureml'

if i go back to terminal and type

```
pip show azureml-core
```

i can indeed see it:

```
Name: azureml-core
Version: 1.53.0
Summary: Azure Machine Learning core packages, modules, and classes
Home-page: https://docs.microsoft.com/python/api/overview/azure/ml/?view=azure-ml-py
Author: Microsoft Corp
Author-email: None
License: https://aka.ms/azureml-sdk-license
Location: c:\python38\tempml\lib\site-packages
Requires: docker, msal, azure-common, paramiko, msrestazure, azure-mgmt-resource, msrest, PyJWT, azure-graphrbac, azure-core, ndg-httpsclient, contextlib2, jmespath, backports.tempfile, adal, argcomplete, urllib3, azure-mgmt-network, cryptography, knack, pkginfo, python-dateutil, jsonpickle, azure-mgmt-keyvault, azure-mgmt-containerregistry, azure-mgmt-storage, humanfriendly, azure-mgmt-authorization, pathspec, pytz, msal-extensions, requests, pyopenssl, packaging, SecretStorage
Required-by:
```

if someone could please help it would be much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the absolute path and then added it using sys:

```
pip show azureml-core
```

then in python:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("c:/python38/tempml/lib/site-packages/")
```

and this now works

Comment: You should accept the answer by clicking on tick icon ✅ which is at left of the answer, so that community can understand that the question has been answered.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you are using an interpreter with the `azureml` module installed. It appears in the lower right corner, click on it to switch interpreters, choosing the **correct** one.

[image]

Also make sure to execute the script using the python extension

[image]

Comment: thank you so much for your help and sorry for slow reply i was tied up at work. I selected the interpreter using control + shift + p but nothing is showing at the bottom right of my screen... i also tried again in Python but i get same error